# Where should I install software in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, ibus

I have an [IME need to install](http://www.trankynam.com/gotv) but the owner doesn't offer file `.deb` nor repo to install. Instead of that, a zip file is all I got. Its instruction said I only need to run `Install.sh` to install. After that, run `ibus` then run `GoTiengViet-IBus` to use. In the end of note, the author wrote

> the directory (the one has Install.sh file) should not be removed.

That is all. I wonder where should I place the directory so I can install the software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some "standard" locations that users tend to install programs:

- `~/.local/`: Created by some applications, most notably aws-cli and allows you to isolate any programs to your user only.
- `~/usr/`: much like the above, with the only difference being that you see it when you `ls` your home directory; This is often the default directory when you compile your own packages
- `/usr/`: Requires root access to install, but not to read, so long as your permissions are set up correctly.

But you can install your program just about anywhere and so long as you know where it is, you will be able to run it.